# How to deleting const array in c++

Tags: c++

I am relatively new in C++. My code reads thousands of images and performs image processing. I want to read a raw image in a function, so I pass string with it's name to the function, and then I create constant char array (as long as I need const char for `fopen`). At the end of the function, I want to delete it. But this throws an exception I cannot fix:

```
extern "C" void imreadTIFF(string location, int x, int y){
    const char * c = location.c_str();
    <code>
    delete [] c;
}


Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

I know, that this question was asked many times. But I didn't find how to fix my problem, also already tried a couple of ways.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: *Don't* delete the pointer you get from `c_str()`.

Comment: Think (!): The temporary string location owns the memory and is destructed anyway. (Pair any new with a delete, but do not introduce an extra delete)

Comment: btw, how do you know? "I know, that this question was asked many times."

Comment: Also, I missed that extern "C", what is that  'string' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string::c_str` returns a pointer to the internal `char` array of the `string`. It must not be deleted by the user because the `string`-object itself will manage its lifetime.

Also, if you do not intend to modify the `string`, pass it as `const string&` instead. If you do in fact modify the `string`-object, be aware that some operations on `string`s invalidate the `.c_str()` pointer.

Comment: So, after function will be finished, this pointer will be deleted automatically? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the point of using a string object instead of a raw pointer to char.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin The memory we are talking about will be freed by the `string` destructor as soon as the lifetime of the `string` object ends. You do not need to manage anything by hand.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll accept answer after some time(cannot do it now)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't used `new[]`, you mustn't use `delete[]`. The program will automatically delete it.